# Percentage difference between two events

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df1 <- 

ID event  CONC
1   1      5
1   2      10
3   1      7
3   2      10
```

For each individual row, I want to calculate the percentage difference in concentration between the two events and add it in a new column.

For example: for ID=1

```
diff <- (10-5)*100
```

I need help in how to specify that (CONCrow2-CONCrow1) for each individual row. Then I can use the following to apply it by ID:

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 mutate (percent = ....)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(percent=100*(CONC-lag(CONC)))
```

Or using `base R`

```
transform(df1, percent=ave(CONC, ID, FUN=function(x) 100*c(NA, diff(x))))
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, percent := 100*c(NA, diff(CONC)), ID]
```

#### Update

Based on @Jan Gorecki's comments, `shift` is a new option available in  `data.table_1.9.5` (devel version)

```
 setDT(df1)[,percent := 100*(CONC - shift(CONC)), by=ID][]
```

Comment: There is a `shift` function available now which can perform `lag` and `lead` better than `diff`.

Comment: @JanGorecki Thanks for the comment.  I updated using `shift`.  It seems  that `unlist` is required here to do the arithmetic operation.  Do you know a better way?

Comment: Only `[[1L]]` comes to my mind, if there are any tricks available then only @Arun will know :)